# Design and implementation for a job pool with dependencies

Tags: c++11, promise, future, channel

I have a collection of data, with "agents" that operate on that data. I have also built up an dependency list between the agents because some agents depend on what other agents do. I also have a structure set up to enforce what data within the collection of data can be accessed or mutated by each agent. I am stuck on how to implement this design, a job pool seems too simple to handling the dependencies  . My question is related to how to actually implement this type of design. The design is very similar to FlowBased programming(if I understand it correctly), but data is operated on in bulk.

My first thought was to have a tree heirarchy of the tasks that need to be done:

```
    Root
   /  |  \
 a1   a2  a3
  | /
 a4
```

For example, I can run a1, a2, and a3 concurrently. But to run a4, a1 and a2 need to be finished.

What would the best tools to set this up? Should I use a signal/slot implementation, roll my own Channels, use futures and promises to emulate a channel/signal/slot system? Maybe make each Node have a number of dependencies, and when each dependent agent finishes a counter is incremented when the next Node is called until it matches the number of deps. Or this could be implemented as a "gate" type of structure that holds the number of deps and sends a signal or w/e to the agent when the deps are satisfied.
I could make make my own TaskManager that does the scheduling, but I'd rather call each top-level Node once, and have the hierarchy automatically traversed. Is their something else entirely I could try. I'm interested in any crazy ideas you might have.

I'm leaning towards something like this, using "signals" and "slots":

```
+----------+    +----------+
|  Actor1  |    |  Actor2  |
| update() |    | update() |
+----|-----+    +----|-----+
      \____    _____/
           \  /   
         +---v---+
         |  Gate |
         +---|---+
             V
        +----------+
        |  Actor4  |
        | update() |
        +----------+
```

How is this type of problem typically tackled? I would like to keep it somewhat generic and use popular libraries if I can. I also need good response times since this will be running in the update() loop of a game engine.

Comment: How many agents are we talking about?  A naive solution is that dependencies are just `std::future`s, and dependency is just the `agent` thread doing a `wait` on each of its inputs.

Comment: The functionality of the agents can be combined if the number gets too high. But right now I have the max set to 256, and I current use 24. There are 11 that have no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object which encapsulates data, and agents working on that data, which together are the underpinnings for the Visitor design pattern. According to the Gang of Four, the intent of the Visitor patter is to

> Represent an operation to be performed on the elements of an object/structure. Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates.

The abstract base visitor, visited classes would have at least the following functionality:

```
class DataElement
{
 public:
   virtual ~DataElement() = default;
   virtual void Accept(DataVisitor*);
 protected:
   DataElement() = default;
};

DataElement::Accept(DataVisitor* v)
{
    v->gendata(this); // double dispatch
}

class DataVisitor
{
 public:
   virtual ~DataVisitor() {} = default;
   virtual void visit_SpreadData(SpreadData*) = 0;   
   virtual void gendata(DataElement*) = 0;
 protected:
   DataVisitor() = default;
};
```

For the chain of responsibility that you are setting up, using a Mediator would be a good start - intent:

> Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. mediator promises loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently.

For that we would modify at least the DataVisitor class to contain a private mediator class. The abstract mediator base class might look something like:

```
class Mediator
{
 public:
   virtual ~Mediator() = default;
   virtual void mediate() = 0;
   std::list<DataVisitor*> get_visitors() const
 protected:
   Mediator() = default;
   virtual void CreateVisitors() = 0;
   std::list<DataVisitor*> visitors_;
};
```

In a concrete mediator class, the one that specifies the behavior in your diagram, the main ingredients are:

1. define private std::mutex, std::condition_variable, and possibly a threadsafe queue;
2. in CreateVisitors(), push a1, a2, a3, a4 onto visitors_ list;
3. create thread methods for each a_i, a1_thread(),a2_thread(),a3_thread() will run immediately, while a4_thread() will wait for the completion of a1, a2, possibly using the results of gendata() (via notify_one()) which have been pushed to the queue;
4. fill in mediate():
   std::vector threadv;
   threadv.emplace_back(&ConcreteMediator::a1_thread, this);
   ...
   threadv.emplace_back(&ConcreteMediator::a4_thread, this);
   std::for_each(threadv.begin(), threadv.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

This is a pretty unsophisticated setup, but it certainly maintains the loose coupling (Mediator) and scalability (Visitor) that you desire.